# How to set radius with specific inches/cm of pie chart on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am making a pie chart using matplotlib and I want to make the radius size exactly 1.5 inches. How can this be done? I know you can set the figure size with specific inches, but this is not what I am trying to do -- I am trying to specifically set the size of the pie chart itself. thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to set the figure size and the padding such that (1-padding)*figuresize results in 1.5 inch. If you have a problem with that, you need to provide a [mcve] of the issue.